# sdl web 8 'this implementation is not part of the windows platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms'

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, upgrade, translation-manager, oracle

Performing the upgrade to SDL Web 8 from 2013 SP1.

Everything went smoothly, except when I ran the actual installation of the `SDLWeb8CM.exe`- Basically following [Installing SDL Web 8 – CM and DB Setup](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/installing-sdl-web-8-cm-and-db-setup/) - except its not a clean install, its an upgrade..

Below is the error I received `sdl web 8 'this implementation is not part of the windows platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms'`

[image]

So I finished the installation, restarted the server, checked the logs:

```
MSI (s) (D8:E0) [17:05:59:405]: Product: SDL Web Topology Manager --     Installation failed.

MSI (s) (D8:E0) [17:05:59:406]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: SDL Web Topology Manager. Product Version: 8.1.1287. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SDL Group. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (s) (D8:E0) [17:05:59:409]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (D8:E0) [17:05:59:409]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:412]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:412]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 5/4/2016  17:05:59 ===
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:419]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:419]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:419]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown.     Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:419]: Note: 1: 1402 2:   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:420]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:420]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (D8:F8) [17:05:59:421]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (D8:EC) [17:05:59:421]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (7C:50) [17:05:59:422]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (7C:50) [17:05:59:423]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 5/4/2016  17:05:59 ===
```

I guess I might need to restore from backup and or try again, anyone else run into this error upgrading? I am using Oracle DB.

**UPDATED**

After successful install of Web 8, and testing WS translation service, I also get this error:

[image]

Comment: That's an odd one, haven't seen it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. I just navigated into the `FipsAlgorithmPolicy` folder and changed the "Enabled" DWORD from 1 to 0 and the install worked just fine from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509354/this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptogra

Comment: The above answer solves the error on install, however the servers keep correcting the `DWORD` fix, from 1 to 0 - possibly on a nightly/hourly basis. I assume it is bc of some policy I do not have insight into at the moment? I have updated the question with same error in different context. The updated translation screenshot in my question above was exposed in translation testing of new Web 8 on the same server and instance where it was fix just an hour ago..